# Как передать недостающие строки из одной DataFrame в другую?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

У меня есть две таблицы "Main_Report" и "New_Report". В таблице "Main_Report" как и в "New_Report" есть строки с одинаковыми датами и названиями продукта.

В обеих таблицах количество одинаковых строк совпадает, кроме строк "Phone".
В "Main_Report" одинаковых строк с "Phone" всего 2, а в "New_Report" их 3.

Я хочу переместить недостающие строки из "New_Report" в "Main_Report". Но мне не подходит метод merge, так как в обеих таблицах есть совпадение, в первом и во втором есть строка с названием продукта phone и идентичной датой, но не совпадает по количеству этих одинаковых строк. И потратив день, я не нашел подходящего урока. Что можно сделать в этой ситуации?

**Main_Report:**

| Product | Date |
| --- | --- |
| Phone | 2022-01-10 |
| Phone | 2022-01-10 |
| Notebook | 2022-01-07 |
| Notebook | 2022-01-06 |
| Notebook | 2022-01-06 |
| PS5 | 2022-01-02 |
| PS5 | 2022-01-01 |

**New_Report:**

| Product | Date |
| --- | --- |
| Phone | 2022-01-10 |
| Phone | 2022-01-10 |
| Phone | 2022-01-10 |
| Notebook | 2022-01-07 |
| Notebook | 2022-01-06 |
| Notebook | 2022-01-06 |
| PS5 | 2022-01-02 |
| PS5 | 2022-01-01 |

```
import pandas as pd

Main_Report = {"Product" : ["Phone","Phone","Notebook","Notebook","Notebook","PS5","PS5",],"Date" : ["2022-01-10","2022-01-10","2022-01-07","2022-01-06","2022-01-06","2022-01-02","2022-01-01",]}
New_Report = {"Product" : ["Phone","Phone","Phone","Notebook","Notebook","Notebook","PS5","PS5",], "Date" : ["2022-01-10","2022-01-10","2022-01-10","2022-01-07","2022-01-06","2022-01-06","2022-01-02","2022-01-01"]}

dfMR = pd.DataFrame(Main_Report)
dfNR = pd.DataFrame(New_Report)

dfMR["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(dfMR["Date"], format="%Y/%m/%d")
dfNR["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(dfNR["Date"], format="%Y/%m/%d")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Из-за дубликатов ничего элегантного в голову не приходит:

```
res = (dfMR
       .assign(x=dfMR.groupby(["Product","Date"]).cumcount())
       .append(dfNR.assign(x=dfNR.groupby(["Product","Date"]).cumcount()), 
               ignore_index=True)
       .drop_duplicates()
       .drop(columns="x"))
```

результат:

```
In [328]: res
Out[328]:
    Product       Date
0     Phone 2022-01-10
1     Phone 2022-01-10
2  Notebook 2022-01-07
3  Notebook 2022-01-06
4  Notebook 2022-01-06
5       PS5 2022-01-02
6       PS5 2022-01-01
9     Phone 2022-01-10
```